# Applying a function when some arguments are constant and some are not

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply

I need to calculate CVfromCI. In this function the arguments `lower`, `upper`, `pe` and `n` are different; the arguments `design`, `alpha`, and `robust` are constants. How can I make my code shorter? Currently I need to write them every time from beginning till the end.

```
library(PowerTOST)

CVfromCI(pe = 0.95, lower = 0.86, upper = 1.029, n = 24, design = "2x2", alpha = 0.05, robust = FALSE)
CVfromCI(pe = 0.94, lower = 0.897, upper = 1.027, n = 24, design = "2x2", alpha = 0.05, robust = FALSE)
CVfromCI(pe = 0.99, lower = 0.88, upper = 1.025, n = 24, design = "2x2", alpha = 0.05, robust = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mapply` to apply the function `CVfromCI` with multiple arguments.

```
library(PowerTOST)

mapply(CVfromCI, 
       pe = c(0.95, 0.94, 0.99),
       lower = c(0.86, 0.897, 0.88),
       upper = c(1.029, 1.027, 1.025),
       n = 24,
       design = "2x2",
       alpha = 0.05,
       robust = FALSE)
# [1] 0.1824596 0.1371548 0.1547650
# Warning messages:
# 1: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input. 
# 2: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input. 
# 3: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input.
```

We can also use `pmap_dbl` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package. Notice that when using `pmap_dbl`, we provide the multiple arguments as a list first, and then the function.

```
library(purrr)

pmap_dbl(list(pe = c(0.95, 0.94, 0.99),
              lower = c(0.86, 0.897, 0.88),
              upper = c(1.029, 1.027, 1.025),
              n = 24,
              design = "2x2",
              alpha = 0.05,
              robust = FALSE),
         CVfromCI)
# [1] 0.1824596 0.1371548 0.1547650
# Warning messages:
# 1: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input. 
# 2: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input. 
# 3: sigma based on pe & lower CL more than 10% different than
# sigma based on pe & upper CL. Check input.
```